# DateDiff and Case operator in an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I'm trying to create a report that helps us identify how we are doing at shipping orders on time, but am quite new to SQL and not quite sure how to achieve what I need to.

We aim to despatch orders that are placed on a weekday before 12pm the same day.  For orders placed after 12pm on a working day, or on a weekend, we aim to ship the order the following working day (Mon-Fri).

I have an initial SQL query that shows all the correct columns and has a CASE operator, but this simply checks if an order was shipped within 24hrs, but doesn't take into account when the order was placed, or on what day.

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,order_datetime,delivery_datetime)<=1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS Ontime_infull
```

The Ontime_infull parameter should be 1 if we achieve the delivery aim, and 0 if we fail.  I'm sure this can be achieved with nested CASE, WHEN, AND etc, but just not sure how to do it.

I have used the following code, which I think is now working, but would be good to get any feedback on whether or not this code could be improved...

```
  CASE 
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Monday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) < 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) =0 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Monday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) >= 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) <=1 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Tuesday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) < 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) =0 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Tuesday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) >= 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) <=1 THEN 1  
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Wednesday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) < 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) =0 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Wednesday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) >= 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) <=1 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Thursday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) < 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) =0 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Thursday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) >= 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) <=1 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Friday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) < 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) =0 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Friday' AND DATEPART(hh,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) >= 12 AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) <=3 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Saturday' AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) <=2 THEN 1
    WHEN DATENAME(dw,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime) = 'Sunday' AND DATEDIFF(Day,order_header_detail.ohd_input_datetime,delivery_header.dh_datetime) <=1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS Ontime_infull
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please improve formatting in your post.

Comment: Thanks Robson and apologies, it was my first ever post.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I understand the problem, but I have no idea what your report is supposed to be looking like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter form to calculate the Ontime_infull flag for the conditions that you have stated:

```
case when
 -- same day delivery is always OK
 (datediff(dd, order_datetime, delivery_datetime) = 0) 
 -- next day deliver is OK if order is after midday
  or ((datepart(hh, order_datetime) >= 12 and datediff(dd, order_datetime, delivery_datetime) = 1))
 -- delivery on the following Monday is OK if ordered after midday on Friday
  or (
      (datepart(hh, order_datetime) >= 12 and datediff(dd, order_datetime, delivery_datetime) <= 3)
       and (((datepart(dw, order_datetime) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1) >= 5) -- Friday or later
       and (((datepart(dw, delivery_datetime) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1) = 1)  -- Monday
     )      
then 1
else 0
```

The `datepart(dw, order_datetime) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1` construct calculates a week day number from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday) independent of the `SET DATEFIRST` setting.

You may also want to look at taking public holidays into account and add a condition for that.